# Post PHP text box with a name and description to a HTML/Rest IIS server

Tags: php, html, rest, iis, visual-studio-2019

Can anyone recommend a site or code example please. I have a php webpage with a form (Name textbox &
question textbox), I want to post form a php web server to an IIS HTML/Rest service, I have installed the Windows Communication module, tried many examples over the past 4 days, I have three files for the Rest service 1. IService1.cs, 2. Service1.cs 3. web.config configured for the end point. I can bin the lot and start again if anyone has any examples. I appreciate anyone's advice, have a great day everyone.

Comment: Do you want to publish the php website to iis? If yes, you can refer to this link: [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/application-frameworks/scenario-build-a-php-website-on-iis/overview-build-a-php-website-on-iis](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/application-frameworks/scenario-build-a-php-website-on-iis/overview-build-a-php-website-on-iis).

Comment: Hi Jack, I'm keeping the PHP website, in the member's area of the PHP site, I have a simple post form where individuals can communicate and I need to keep the communications stored on an MSSQL database for 6 years should any discrepancies arise (advised by our legal team), I want those messages to post to the IIS server and save to my MSSQL db, I thought the best way would be to use HTML/Rest, but never using HTML/Rest, I can't find a code example to post from PHP to the IIS endpoint and looking for the best endpoint code to receive from PHP. All the best David

Comment: What is HTML/Rest? I only know Rest, can you explain it in detail?

Comment: Hi, I'm brand new to Rest, the first example I seen was titled HTML/Rest, you will be right, it must just be Rest, apologies, I will use that term going forward. Thanks Samwu